# Is there any other country aside Thailand that criminalized cannabis after legalizing it?

Tags: thailand, cannabis-legalization

According to [CNN](https://www.cnn.com/2024/01/10/asia/thailand-cannabis-reverse-proposed-laws-intl-hnk/index.html):

> Thailand’s new government is moving ahead to pass new legislation
> banning cannabis for recreational use in a major reversal 18 months
> after the country became the first in Asia to decriminalize the plant.
>
> The relaxed laws saw a lucrative cannabis industry catering to locals
> and foreigners alike boom across the Southeast Asian nation, but a new
> conservative coalition government came to power late last year vowing
> to tighten the rules and only allow medical use.
>
> A draft bill was released on Tuesday by Thailand’s health ministry
> outlining hefty fines or prison sentences of up to one year for
> offenders – or both. It also welcomed feedback from the public.

The article from CNN describes how Thailand decided to prohibit cannabis after legalizing it. I was wondering if there's a precedent in the world where a country legalized cannabis and decided to prohibit it later on.

Comment: I assume you mean in recent years, because cannabis was legal until the early 20th century in many places ([US law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_history_of_cannabis_in_the_United_States)).

Comment: @StuartF: But they weren't banned and then legalized and then banned again, which is what OP is asking about. In the early 20th century, marijuana was for the first time banned in many places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Egypt:

> in 1266 Babar embarked on a total ban of both cultivation and consumption. ...
>
> Babar's successor, al-Mansur Galawan [r. 1279–90], reversed this repressive policy against drugs and tried a liberal approach. He imposed an excise tax on the sale of hashish and wine. Although his new policy generated revenues, it also resulted in an increased alcohol and hashish consumption to such a degree that this liberal reformer was forced to reimpose prohibition to protect his society's future.

(Source: Nahas, 1982, "Hashish In Islam 9th to 18th Century", [PDF](https://europepmc.org/backend/ptpmcrender.fcgi?accid=PMC1805385&blobtype=pdf).)

Answer (score 4):

Questions that ask if some hypothetical thing exists are problematic. I suspect the answer is  "no" but how to prove this?

[The US state of Virginia](https://norml.org/blog/2022/06/01/virginia-approved-budget-recriminalizes-public-marijuana-possession-over-4-ounces/) recriminalized cannabis, and [the city of Sarasota, FL](https://patch.com/florida/sarasota/recriminalization-marijuana-possession-works-sarasota-report) recently made moves to do the same.

But as for entire countries, Thailand may be the first and only so far.

Feel free to comb through [the timeline on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_cannabis_law) to find something I may have overlooked.